# Using ISO files from Synology NAS share for Hyper-V

Tags: nas, iso-image, hyper-v, synology, sharing

I am trying to install a virtual machine in Hyper-V, using an ISO file laying on a Synology NAS share.

But when i try to create the machine, and mount the ISO this pops up:
**The device 'Microsoft:Hyper-V:Virtual CD/DVD Disk' was not added to 'MachineName'**

But i can access the share fine with File Explorer.

Do you know of anything that blocks this kind of use?

Comment: I've had occasional problems with larger files like ISOs or entire VM files on a Synology NAS.  Never have figured out exactly why, but copying the file to the local PC's HDD and using it from there has solved each of these problems for m.

Comment: Hmm okay. Seems a bit weird when i can use a 3 gig movie file fine, but not ISO files. But thanks for the answer! Good to see im not the only one.

Comment: Answer?  Well ... maybe.  Suggestion, but answer, or workaround, I hope.

Comment: I meant "Thanks for response" :) Not my first language

Comment: No worries.  I knew what you meant.  It's MY first language, but I don't always use it as well as I should. ;-)

Comment: This question is old but the reason is probably with Hyper-V not using your credentials to access the file share.

Answer (score 1):

[DSM 6] You could mount the ISO as a virtual drive on the Synology via Synology FileStation, where the contents of the ISO is exposed as a subdirectory?

**Rightclick the ISO file in FileStation and choose Mount Virtual Drive**
[image: Mount ISO in Synology FileStation Step 1]

**Enter the 'mount to' path** and choose "Mount"
[image: Mount ISO in Synology FileStation Step 2]

**See the mounted ISO directory in FileStation**
[image: Mount ISO in Synology FileStation Step 3]

Next use the path from your Hyper-V.

Comment: Nice, thank you for the response. Im in the middel of migrating to a newer model Synology, therefore i can't try at the moment. But definitely will!